# How to save the rss feed in to Core Data database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, rss

I parsed rss feed from websites and show on table view by using GDataXML but I want my app can work offline. I am newbie for iPhone development and I don't know how to save it in Core Data.

Answer (score 2):

You create a Core Data Model in XCode. You'll probably need a `Post` entity to represent RSS posts. Possible properties might be `Title`, `Content`, `Date` etc. Maybe you'll also need a `Feed` entity to store all the feeds the user is subscribed to.

Then, after downloading the XML and parsing it, you initialize these managed objects with these entities in your context and save them.

I recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).

And of course [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html). It's a lengthly read, but if you want to build a stable and high quality app you won't get around it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite general and is difficult to answer in a detailed manner.

About Core Data I really suggest to read [core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).

It's a good intro on Core Data.

Once read, you could understand the model I will suggest. For example, you could create a simply enitity called `RSSFeed` that has the two following properties:

- `guid`: a `NSString` identifier for your feed
- `title`: a `NSString` title for your feed
- `text`: a `NSString` text that allows you to diplay the text for your feed
- `date`: a `NSDate` date for the feed insertion date

There could be other props (and/or entities) but it depends on what do you want to display for your feed.

Furthermore, [The Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) is your friend.

Hope that helps.